# Training data and get the weight for each feature

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

We are developing a recommendation system, and I get the problem of the attrs may be vectors themselves.

So, for now, the company already have a function to list the recommendation list to users, but the weight of each feature what they used is defined manually. So we decided to train the data and then get the weight with the approach Machine learning first. And then get the feedback from users which will be the label to do the next prediction of recommendation.

1. Is there any ideal to get the best weight for each feature? such as grid_search, Gradient descent?
2. I think we cannot flat (sklearn: one hot encoding or pandas: get_dummies) the feature which value is a vector. because I wanna get the weight of the feature instead of subfeature_1, subfeaturevalue_2.
   So, flatten is not working here, I have to try to change the distance to do it? but how to combine (change distance function and use grid_search) them together?

Answer (score 0):

Getting features weights could be done using neural networks (back-propagation). You can use a single perceptron if you want avoid using NN.
[Here](https://github.com/slrbl/perceptron-text-classification-from-scracth) (the explanation is [here](http://enigmater.blogspot.com/2018/01/perceptron-based-text-classifier-from.html))is an example of single perceptron algorithm applied on text classification, you will need to adapt it to your features.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Grasin98/recommender_live for basics of recommendation system.Hope you find it relevant.

You can visit this. Yes, there are algorithms like grid search which can be helpful for finding best weight matrix.

Grid search means you have a set of models (which differ from each other in their parameter values, which lie on a grid). What you do is you then train each of the models and evaluate it using cross-validation. You then select the one that performed best.

To give a concrete example, if you're using a support vector machine, you could use different values for gamma and C. So, for example you could have a grid with the following values for (gamma, C): (1, 1), (0.1, 1), (1, 10), (0.1, 10). It's a grid because it's like a product of [1, 0.1] for gamma and [1, 10] for C. Grid-search would basically train a SVM for each of these four pair of (gamma, C) values, then evaluate it using cross-validation, and select the one that did best.

For Gradient Descent:
The first step of the procedure requires that the order of the training dataset is randomized. This is to mix up the order that updates are made to the coefficients. Because the coefficients are updated after every training instance, the updates will be noisy jumping all over the place, and so will the corresponding cost function. By mixing up the order for the updates to the coefficients, it harnesses this random walk and avoids it getting distracted or stuck.
The learning can be much faster with stochastic gradient descent for very large training datasets and often you only need a small number of passes through the dataset to reach a good or good enough set of coefficients, e.g. 1-to-10 passes through the dataset.

So according to me, there is know the Perfect method. It basically depends on a number of things. As you might know, this is the same for algorithm application SVM, Decision Tree, Random Forest, all give variation with respect to the situation.

As per the second question is concerned, I not sure what it is trying to convey.
Hope this helps.